# Unbound variable error when using defmacro in LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I am trying to use macro with two forms in LISP, which evaluates both forms but always return the result of form 2. Below is the code that I am using -

```
(defmacro testmac (x body) (prog2 x body))
```

When executing the macro with following forms, It works correctly and always return 5 which is the second form.

```
(testmac (- 10 6) (/ 10 2))
```

However when I try to execute macro with following forms, its return error.

```
(testmac (print a) (print b))
```

Below is the error I get -

```
debugger invoked on a UNBOUND-VARIABLE: The variable B is unbound.
Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.
restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.
(SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV B #<NULL-LEXENV>)
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I use macro to make this work?

P.S. I cannot use defun need to use macro to execute (testmac (print a) (print b))

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! This is a well-formed first question.

However... Please write “Lisp”, w/o caps ;)

Comment: @ Ealhad. Sure and thanks for your advise.

Comment: You are very welcome! Good luck and happy hacking.

Comment: @Rainer @ Ealhad, thank you all for your feedback and suggestion. Based on what you all have pointed out, I am executing code as    (testmac (print 'a) (print 'b)) which returns B and no errors. It solves the original problem that I was trying to sole, i.e. use macro and prog2 to evaluate both forms (@rainer, I understand it isn't advisable) and return result of the second form. I hoe that this is the correct resolution and not a workaround. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

> I am trying to use macro with two forms in LISP, which evaluates both forms but always return the result of form 2.

That's usually not a good idea - though it might be just not precise wording. A macro should not evaluate code - not without a good reason. Usually the macro just transforms code. The generated code then decides what to evaluate.

```
(defmacro testmac (x body) (prog2 x body))

(testmac (- 10 6) (/ 10 2))
```

So `x` is the list `(- 10 6)` and body is the list `(/ 10 2)`.

Your macro returns the second list.

```
CL-USER 11 > (macroexpand-1 '(testmac (print a) (print b)))
(PRINT B)
```

The macro returns the form `(print b)`. It then gets executed.

```
CL-USER 12 > (testmac (print a) (print b))

Error: The variable B is unbound.
```

If `B` is undefined you get the error you see.

There is no magic going on.

Answer (score 3):

That's because your `testmac` macro directly executes `(prog2 x body)`, instead of expanding into it.

You need to write it like this:

```
(defmacro testmac (x body)
  `(prog2 ,x ,body))
```

The form after the backquote won't be evaluated, but those after a comma will.

You can (and you should!) test the expansion like this:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(testmac (print 42) (print 51)))
```

Which gives:

```
(PROG2 (PRINT 42) (PRINT 51))
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. 1. Both (PROG2 (PRINT 42) (PRINT 51)) and testmac (print 42 and print 51) return the result correctly. However when I am trying to execute (prog2 (print a) (print b)) it doesn't work again and returns error -    debugger invoked on a UNBOUND-VARIABLE: The variable PROG2 is unbound

Comment: Uh, that's weird. The only way I found to reproduce this error was with `prog2 (print a) (print b)`, without the outer parens, which fails for a pretty good reason.

Comment: @MikeRandor Just to be clear, when you replace `testmac` with `progn`, ei. `(progn (print a) (print b))` , you are not getting the error?

Comment: @Sylwester, based on what Rainer has pointed out, (progn (print a) (print b)) will return and it is resulting in error, as progn/ prog2 is evaluating a and b which are  undefined. I tried to solve the problem by executing (testmac (print 'a) (print 'b)) which worked without error and printed "b".